# How to get bash to ignore file-not-founds

Tags: bash, file-not-found

In a (ba)sh script, how do I ignore file-not-found errors?

I am writing a script that reads a (partial) filename from stdin, using:

```
read file; $FILEDIR/$file.sh
```

I need to give the script functionality to reject filenames that don't exist.

e.g.

`$UTILDIR` does NOT contains `script.sh`
User types script
Script tries to access `$UTILDIR/script.sh` and fails as

```
./run.sh: line 32: /utiltest/script.sh: No such file or directory
```

How do I make the script print an error, but continue the script without printing the 'normal' error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test whether the file exists using the code in @gogaman's answer, but you are probably more interested in knowing whether the file is present *and executable*. For that, you should use the `-x` test instead of `-e`

```
if [ -x "$FILEDIR/$file.sh" ]; then
   echo file exists
else
   echo file does not exist or is not executable
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ -e $FILEDIR/$file.sh ]; then
 echo file exists;
else
 echo file does not exist;
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we can define a shell procedure that runs only if the file exists

```
run-if-present () {
  echo $1 is really there
}

[ -e $thefile ] && run-if-present $thefile
```

Comment: That introduces a race condition.

Comment: @tikiking1: The file might be deleted between the test and the command, so it's possible that in `run-if-present` the file is actually not present. `run-if-present` still has to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you do with the script, the command will fail with a specific exit code. If you are executing the script, the exit code can be 126 (permission denied) or 127 (file not found).

```
command
if (($? == 126 || $? == 127))
then
  echo 'Command not found or not executable' > /dev/stderr
fi
```

Comment: This I appended (a modified version) that receives the utility's returns. While not being exactly what I was searching for this was helpful.